# How do I call a javascript function when a button is clicked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now I am using:

```
<%=button_to_function "✓", checkButton(), :class => "buttonGrey"%>
```

But the javascript function needs something to be passed to it so it can toggle the class( I want the buttons class to be changed upon pressing it) What would I pass as a param to represent the button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute javascript directly in the button_to_function.

In your case:

`<%= button_to_function "✓", '$(this).toggleClass("buttonGrey buttonGreen");', :class => "buttonGrey" %>`

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. I kept having a of problems with actually trying to call a function. Thank you!

Comment: button_to_function is deprecated (again) in Rails 4.  For some reason it has been in and our of Rails a couple times.  Details and alternative solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324919/status-of-rails-link-to-function-deprecation

Answer (score 10):

Since "**button_to_function**" is deprecated since Rails 4.0.2, now you can use "**button_tag**" helper.

Exemple:

```
<%= button_tag "Do It", type: 'button', onclick: "myFunction()", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
```

**Note**: If you use CoffeeScript, declare your function as:

```
window.myFunction =>
  ...
```

because in CofeeScript, functions are not global scoped by default.

Comment: It works. Tiny correction(s) for the button_tag: enter a comma before 'type' and skip the 'do'.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `checkButton()`, you should be able to access `this` and manipulate it using jQuery or whatever your framework is.

For example, using jquery:

```
$(this).toggleClass("buttonGrey buttonGreen");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use straight up jquery.

```rb
$(".buttonGrey").on("click", function() {
  // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the on click event inside the button tag