# Why is button_to_function method undefined (RoR)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just starting out in Ruby on Rails so sorry for the n00bish Q…

I want to make a button that triggers some javascript. I found [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296723/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-when-a-button-is-clicked) that lead me to writing the following code:

```
<%= button_to_function "Change Password", "$(this).toggle();", :class =>"password_div" %>
```

(Elsewhere, I have `<div class="password_div" style="display: none;">…</div>` tags.)

The issue is that when I run this code I get the following error:

```
undefined method `button_to_function' for #<<Class:0x00000006abc1c8>:0x0000000647ee00>
```

Which I find confusing. My impression is that this comes standard in Rails (it is listed [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html) along with lots of other methods that as far as I can tell *are* available immediately in RoR).

Do I need to *make* JavaScript Helper available somewhere? Or am I missing something somewhere else?

Comment: The official [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org) don't know about `button_to_function` and the comments on the linked question indicate that it went away in Rails4. Perhaps the guides are out of date. In any case, you'd be better off creating a `<button>` and then binding a handler to it separately.

Comment: Ah, ok…thanks!
When you say "bind a handler to it separately", you mean to make regular old javascript handler? Nothing in RoR should/need be done?

Comment: That's correct.  I strongly suggest you read through the Rails book before going further.

Comment: Right, `button_to_function` probably went away because it was some nasty old-school `<button onclick="...">` stuff that smells like 1998. Just make a `<button>` and add a `$(appropriate_selector).click(...)` binding in your (Coffee|Java)Script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's been [removed](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3475e0ed2402009a72c8e1a4dbf0632c24679fdc/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb#L83) (Source code):

```
  def button_to_function(name, function=nil, html_options={})
    message = "button_to_function is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 4.1. We recommend using Unobtrusive JavaScript instead. " +
      "See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript"
    ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn message

    onclick = "#{"#{html_options[:onclick]}; " if html_options[:onclick]}#{function};"

    tag(:input, html_options.merge(:type => 'button', :value => name, :onclick => onclick))
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, especially for the link about unobtrusive JS!